# Adding assembly reference in windows phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, .net-assembly, qr-code

Actually I am doing qr code scan app, I am using below code

```
xmlns:jwqr="clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"
```

in xaml

```
<jwqr:QRCodeScanner
    ScanComplete="QRCodeScanner_ScanComplete"
    Error="QRCodeScanner_Error"
    Width="400"
    Height="400"/>
```

it showing error like The name "QRCodeScanner" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"

but i didn't find where is the assembly reference.please provide any path for adding assembly reference.

Comment: Hi, this library is not fofr WP8.1, you still need to find a working library. I will delete my answer as it does not help.

Comment: @kennyzx please provide any sample code for qrcode scanning. I need please

Comment: @Bo Persson Please provide any links for qr code scanning.I need

Comment: @Anil - sorry I have no info on that. I just retagged the question from assembly language programming to .NET assemblies (totally different).